# How to enable other passes on background layer?

Tags: render-passes

[image: Here's]
Here's what my compositor shows when I have shadow pass enabled. How do I enable it for the background layer as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution, I needed to change the render layer in the top right. Once it was changed to background I was able to enable the shadow pass for that layer as well

[image: render layers]

Answer (score 2):

In the View Layer Properties tab you can see all the render passes availables.

[image: Light]
[image: Passes]